# Javascript stringify() is serializing elements removed with Jquery remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization, stringify

I have a custom page builder in an ASP.Net MVC project which uses jquery and javascript to dynamically build up the elements on the page, which is then serialised using stringify() method and passed to the controller as a string which then saves the serialised Json as a string in the SQL database. I have given each element on the page a delete button, which is nested within the div of the element. I have given the delete button a javascript function which deletes its parent div including itself from the page. This works. But, bizarrely and, even though I have inspected the page and found no trace of the deleted div or its unique data-attribute identifiers, the previously removed elements are still serialised on call of stringify().

As stated above, I have inspected the elements to ensure that Jquery.remove() is actually removing them, which it appears to be. Everything on the page appears to work as desired, but there is some sort of remnants of the elements left behind which is being serialised and I'm not sure how to counter this.

The elements appear like this:

```
<div data-myhtmlelement='text'><input type='hidden' data-myhtmlvalue='myval' /><a href='#' data-myhtmldeletebtn></a></div>

    The jquery is along these lines:
    // deleting...
    $("[data-myhtmlelement]").each(function(index, element){
        $(element).find("[data-myhtmldeletebtn]").click(function(){
        $(element).remove();
        });
    });
```

I then, on click of a submit button further down the page, target each of my data-myhtmlelement items again, and stringify them in an array. But it is picking up the removed element. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Just to help move this along, do I perhaps need some way of updating the elements present inside of my submit function? I had assumed, given that only on click of my submit button does the code execute, that this button would check the elements that exist at the time of submitting. This is certainly the case after I've added elements on the fly.

Comment: Can you share sample input for the above code. It is hard to figure out what the issue could be looking at asp.net code mixed with jQuery. If you're dealing with JSON object in click handler, you can use Javascript's delete operator to remove that attribute from the object. For precise solution share the json/sample input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This was a really simple issue actually; I had declared my items as a variable outside of the submit function, so I needed to set the items variable inside the submit function, so as to have an up to date cache of the elements on the page. Really silly mistake, but I hope this helps someone else. I am happy to have this closed now.

Comment: Based on last comment you should delete this question since not enough is shown to even see that sequence